# How to list softwares installed in my system

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, pkg-config

As far as I studied, `pkg-config` command returns the info about all the libraries installed in my Linux system. Can anyone specify me from where does it get these details?

Also, where will I get the details(at least name) of the softwares installed. I have tried `dpkg --get-selections` command. But it lists all packages. i.e., if `rhythmbox` is the software installed, it lists the following:

```
rhythmbox                       install
rhythmbox-data                  install
rhythmbox-mozilla               install
rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder     install
rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune      install
rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist      install
rhythmbox-plugins               install
```

Is there some way by which I can list only the name of the software?

Comment: pkg-config gets its information from `.pc` files. Read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dpkg` to list all the packages installed in your system.

`dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall`

You can use the **apt** also using the below command.

`aptitude search '~i'`

And the last option is you can use the package managers like `synaptic` it comes with a good user interface also.

Comment: Is it specific for `debian` systems?

Comment: Yeah `dpkg` comes with debian.

Comment: you can use the `apt` also using the following command `aptitude search '~i'`.

Comment: It also lists all packages  associated with the software.